# Unit testing of a very dynamic web application?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, qunit

My business web application (PHP with HTML/Javascript) has lots of very different options (about 1000) which are stored in the database, so the users can change them theirselves. These options for example define if a button, tab or inputfield is visible, the validation of inputs and the workflow, like when e-mails should be sent. Each user has a user-role, which *also* defines what they're able to see and do.

My users can use any combination of these options, so I find it very difficult to write tests for all these situations. I have 100+ customers so writing tests for each customer is definetely not an option.

The problem is that some options work together. So while testing one option it's necessary to know the value of some other options. Ideally the tests should also be able to read the options-profiles for each customer. But that would almost be like rewriting the whole application, just for testing, which seems error-prone by itself.

Is it common in unit testing to read the database to get the test-data and options, or is that not a good idea?
How would you handle the situation I described ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all yes, that's perfectly possible. Although it's not recommended to write unit tests after the application is already written and its extremely difficult.

Here are a few advises for your case:

1. Data Providers

Data Providers are making it possible to call the same test with different parameters, which prevents code duplication in your tests. Perfect if you want to test the same method with different configurations.

https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers

2. Mock objects

If objects depend on other objects you use mock objects. Mocking an object is basically nothing more than creating a dummy object which has a defined behavior and won't do anything else than the things you told it to do.
Note that you can also mock the tested class itself! A mock will keep the methods of the mocked class by default, so you can mock the class you want to test and define a specific behavior for some methods while testing another.
If this is still not enough, you might want to think about splitting up you methods in smaller, more specific methods to get smaller units.

https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html

2. Keep it small

Unit tests are called unit tests because they test the smallest possible unit of your code without executing anything else. So instead of testing if a button behaves the way it should, just test if its visible if it should be. Just test *one* kind of behavior and nothing more.

3. Don't read the database

It is highly unusual to read the database when writing unit tests and its even more unusual to use actual user data. Instead you define test data. Instead of testing your users configuration, you should test every possible configuration

4. Code Coverage

A decent way to check if your code is covered by the tests is code coverage. It will show you how much and which code was executed by the tests. Although 100% coverage does not mean full coverage in reality, specially in your case. Just because all lines of code were executed does not mean every option was considered. But its a handy tool anyways and you can see which code you are done with and which you forgot about.

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html

5. Conclusion:

What you are trying to do is error-prone itself, yes. Because usually you'd write all your tests before writing the actual method. And you will probably write more test code than the application has itself, but that's not uncommon.